# Export kyr key of Domino server to PEM or PKCS12

Tags: ssl-certificate, lotus-domino

A Lotus Domino is configured for SSL. How to export his certificat (stored in keyring files with .kyr extension).

This means that I need an SSL certificate for the Domino website on the AN OTHER server (like a reverse proxy)
My problem is almost the same as the one exposed in http://labs.groupwave.be/index.php/2009/08/31/exporting-kyr-certificate-for-apache/

I've also read:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=463&context=SSKTMJ&q1=export+ssl+certificate&uid=swg21097215&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en 
which explains that it's not possible.

So it works or not ? Maybe am I confusing private key and public key ? Do I need the private key or the public is sufficient on the other server?

Comment: Please ask this question on serverfault.com instead

Comment: Good idea, I flag my question for requiring moderator attention on this (like suggested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-overflow-sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for who google here...
The best way to know "if it works?" is "try and trust yourself!".

So yes! It works! Many credits to http://labs.groupwave.be/index.php/2009/08/31/exporting-kyr-certificate-for-apache/

the OTHER server needs the private key! (BTW simple sense of logic if anyone with your public certificate could do the trick it would mean no security)